# create array from specific classes texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to create an array from all `planet` text:

```
<div class='planet'>earth</div>
<div class='planet'>sun</div>
<div class='planet'>moon</div>

var planets = JSON.stringify(Array.from($('.planet').text()));

console.log(planets);
```

In console I need:

```
["earth","sun","moon"]
```

Any help?

Comment: Wouldn’t that be just `console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".planet"), ({textContent}) => textContent));` — without jQuery?

Comment: @Xufox thanks, didn't realise `Array.from` supported a mapping function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use each function in jquery to traverse all the elements and then push in array.

```js
planets=[]
$('.planet').each(function(){
planets.push($(this).text())
});

console.log(planets);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='planet'>earth</div>
<div class='planet'>sun</div>
<div class='planet'>moon</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all those elements, use `Array.from` to get an array, and use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate an array from it.

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".planet")).map(t => t.innerText));
```

```html
<div class='planet'>earth</div>
<div class='planet'>sun</div>
<div class='planet'>moon</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **jQuery.each**

```js
var planets = [];

$('.planet').each((i, e) => planets.push($(e).text()));

console.log(planets);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='planet'>earth</div>
<div class='planet'>sun</div>
<div class='planet'>moon</div>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `i, e` arguments in your example ?

Comment: @puerto - Nothing over here they are not required. Though `i` means the index and `e` means the element.

Comment: @puerto - I have updated the answer. See I can use `e` in place of `this` for getting values. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];

document.querySelectorAll('.planet').forEach(elem => {
  arr.push(elem.textContent);
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div class='planet'>earth</div>
<div class='planet'>sun</div>
<div class='planet'>moon</div>
```